# Geopandas invalid field type

Tags: python, geopandas, shapefile

i am trying to export a geodataframe as a shapefile and I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Invalid field type <class 'list'>
```

These are the dtypes of the columns:

```
gdf.dtypes
Out[196]: 
Text                   object
Id_Tweet               object
Id_User                object
Username               object
Likes                   int64
Retweets                int64
Quotes                  int64
Replies                 int64
Geo                    object
Place_Type             object
Place_Name             object
Id_Place               object
Referenced Tweets      object
bbox                   object
lat                   float64
lon                   float64
geometry             geometry
dtype: object
```

Is it an error related to the dtypes?

Kind regards,
Daniel

Comment: yeah... you have an invalid field type, of type list. we can't help more without a complete example with the full code and a [traceback](//realpython.com/python-traceback). See this guide on creating a [minimal reproducible example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapefile#Data_storage - you can't store lists as attributes in a shapefile

Comment: `gdf.head(10)` should reveal which column is causing the issue.  You can either exclude column using `.loc[]` or do something like `gdf["colname"].apply(",".join)` to covert column from **list** to delimited

Answer (score 0):

If you don't really need the list type afterwards, you can convert it to string using:

```
df['dtype_list_column'] = df['dtype_list_column'].astype(str)
```

and then the geoDataFrame is saved without hiccups and without loss of info.